# How can i simulate "taxonomy__in" in query?

Tags: wp-query, tax-query

How can I have to set tax_query to get results like 'category__in' => array()?

Specifically, I would like to show all the posts that have a term from the city taxonomy with one of these id's: `$cities = array(23,34,45,56);`

This is the code I currently use.

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
    array(
            'key' => 'mar_bedrooms',
            'value' => $bedroomss,
            'compare' => 'IN'
        ),
    array(
            'key' => 'mar_property_for',
            'value' => $property_forss,
            'compare' => 'IN'
        ),
    array(
        'key' => 'mar_price',
        'value' => array( $price_min, $price_max ),
        'type' => 'numeric',
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
        )
    ),
    'post_status'=>'publish',
    'post_type'=>'post',
    //'cat' => 1,
    'category__in'=> $type,
    //'taxonomy__in'=> $city,
    'orderby'=>'date',
    'order'=>'DESC'
);
query_posts($args);

if ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();
    $a = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't, because of the way categories and general taxonomies operate. Categories are a type of taxonomy, so we are querying one level lower when querying for categories. When you query for `category__in => array()` it actually looks up what `category_terms` are queried and queries posts from all those categories. Now this effect we can mimic.

```
$terms_in = array(23,34,45,56);
$taxonomy_terms = get_terms( array( 'city' ), array(
    'orderby' => 'none',
    'hide_empty' => 1,
    'include' => $terms_in
) );

foreach ( $taxonomy_terms as $term ) :
    $args = array(
        'taxonomy' => $term->slug,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );

    $term_name = $term->slug;
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    while( $query->has_posts() ) : 
        $query->the_post();
        // DISPLAY HERE
    endwhile;

endforeach;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

The code above was edited for your specific question.

Comment: I registered a new taxonomy city, in frontend of site i have a search form who filters by metakeys, category, and taxonomy city. So i have to show posts that match that filters also if i have to list post from one city is simple but if i have to list all cities then i have to use taxonomy__in, but of course isn't available.

Comment: @Marius Ah. Do you want to list all the cities? Or all the posts in all the cities?

Comment: All the posts who have city taxonomy in $cities = array(23,34,45,56).

Comment: Edited the code accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

After 3 days of research i found the good way to simulate taxonomy_in.

```
      $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'mar_bedrooms',
                'value' => $bedroomss,
                'compare' => 'IN'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'mar_bathrooms',
                'value' => $bathroomses,
                'compare' => 'IN'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'mar_property_for',
                'value' => $property_forss,
                'compare' => 'IN'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'mar_price',
                'value' => array( $price_min, $price_max ),
                'type' => 'numeric',
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
            )
        ),
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'city',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $city,  //$city can be also an array
                'operator' => 'IN'
            )
        ),
        'post_status'=>'publish',
        'category__in'=> $type,  //$type can be also an array
        'orderby'=>'date',
        'order'=>'DESC'
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ($the_query->have_posts()) : while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
wp_reset_query();
wp_reset_postdata();
```